# SSJS functions not working for Data Extension objects

Tags: marketing-cloud, javascript, api, soap-api, dataextensions

I'm trying to retrieve the CustomObjectID of a data extension that already exists, by using the External Key/CustomerKey. That didn't work, so now I'm trying to retrieve any DEs at all, and *that's* not working either. Here is my code, I'm running it in a Landing page:

```
<script runat="server">
Platform.Load("Core","1");
var clientID = Attribute.GetValue('memberid');

var api = new Script.Util.WSProxy();
api.setClientId({"ID": clientID});
var cols = [ "Name", "CustomerKey", "CategoryID", "IsSendable"];
var res = api.retrieve("DataExtension",cols);
Write(res);

</script>
```

I don't get a JSON object back. What is written out is:

```
System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String, System.Object]
```

I don't know what this means, except that there are no data extension objects to return?
I'm literally following the exact example in the documentation:-

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/ssjs_WSProxy_basic_retrieve.htm

I can't even get the describe function to work:

```
var res = api.describe("DataExtension");
```

returns the same result -

```
System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,System.Object]
```

To add to the confusion, I can use describe and retrieve QueryDefinition objects and emailSendDefinition objects just fine - no issue there.

Answer (score 2):

Change the last line to:

`Write(Stringify(res));`

Stringify will display the res variable that contains the response as JSON key and values with double quotes.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/95315)

Comment: A bit harsh @DavidReed ?

Comment: @data_kid This answer was edited after I saw it in Review. At the time, it was a comment that did not provide an answer, but has been improved.

Comment: Stringify() does not work  - it need an object. Since I'm not getting a JSON object back as a response, I just get an error that Stringify() is expecting an object.

Answer (score 0):

turns out the issue was with the Stringify function. I did not notice it at the time, but I had a lowercase 's' in my code:

```
Write(stringify(res));
```

When I should have had

```
Write(Stringify(res));
```

And now everything actually works. The code block where I was using describe for QueryDefinition and EmailSendDefinition had the correct capitalized Stringify().

Lesson learned: starting a new code project on Friday afternoon before a holiday weekend is just not a good idea.